# Calculating radius of curvature and banking angle when set of lat, long and elevation are given?

Tags: gps, assisted-gps, gpstools

[image]

I have set of lat,long and elevation values with me. Can you help me find the Radius of curve and banking angle.

Formulae may be provided as an answer.

Comment: Is this related to road design?

Comment: @Techie_Gus Not road design. We are working on devices that warn the driver through some signals that there is a curve ahead

Comment: What information do you have that could possibly be used to calculate bank angle? Do you know if the road is even banked?

Comment: @BradHards With the elevation, I think we can find banking angle

Comment: Do you have elevation angles for both sides of the road? If all you have is centreline position (or inside, or outside), it might be no bank, it might be banked at 30 or more degrees. Show the data you have.

Answer (score 2):

It is a geometric exercise.
PSEUDOCODE:

Connect points approaching turn one by one. 
Break if line is not a straight line anymore (apply tolerance).
Draw line perpendicular to the end:
[image]
Repeat steps above by approaching bend from opposite direction:
[image]
Intersection of perpendiculars is approximate (due to uncertainties with start-of-turn points) centre of circle making fillet line:
[image]

Average distance from circle centre to 2 start-of-turn points is your radius

Comment: Is there a way to do it programmatically ?

Comment: Yes, the steps are outlined in pseudo code above